# Android seek bar/ progress bar with no click

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am fairly new to the android platform. I have to implement a SeekBar or a ProgressBar with the following constraint: it should not be clickable. I only want to allow my users to change the value of the bar by dragging it not by clicking on it. I have not found any solutions for that so far. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Default behavior like this is in place so that users know what to expect when they interact with similar UI elements across different apps. Disabling or altering this default behavior without very good reason is usually considered user-hostile.

Comment: The client requested it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progressbar by default is not clickable :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did u tried this for that seekbar

```
android:clickable="false"
```